# Issue Updating to Glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, glassfish

I recently updated one of our test servers to use Glassfish 4.1. I am having an issue deploying our Web Services to Glassfish after this update. When deploying the application I get the message "Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor” (see full stack trace below).

I originally thought this issue revolved around a customized Guava jar (added a beans.xml to circumvent compatibility issue) we use. I rebuilt the application using the newest Guava release (18) and still ran into the same issue deploying to Glassfish 4.1. The application has no issues deploying to Glassfish 4.0 with the latest Guava version.

```
[2014-09-23T10:15:37.589-0600] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=177 _ThreadName=admin-listener(25)] [timeMillis: 14114
88937589] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication start method
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.setStartedState(BaseContainer.java:962)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.markAllContainersAsStarted(EjbApplication.java:140)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.start(EjbApplication.java:152)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
        ....
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.buildEjbInterceptorChain(InterceptorManager.java:431)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.<init>(InterceptorManager.java:131)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeInterceptorManager(BaseContainer.java:3396)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.setStartedState(BaseContainer.java:950)
        ... 83 more
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug:

https://java.net/jira/browse/HK2-233
https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2661

Unfortunately Oracle doesn't release patches for GlassFish but only major releases (AFAIK). One alternative is to use [the GlassFish fork "Payara"](http://www.payara.co.uk).

You can apply this standard conform workaround:

```
private <T> boolean beanIsValid(final T bean) {
    final Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
    final Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(bean);

    return constraintViolations.isEmpty();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into exactly the same problem you were having with some old exercises I'm doing. I just used Glassfish 4.1.2 and it solved the problem for me.

https://download.java.net/glassfish/4.1.2/release/glassfish-4.1.2.zip